# Rename all files in a directory to that of another directory

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

I have two directories, foo and bar. Both contain the same number of files. I wish to rename all the files in foo to the same as the files in bar. Meaning the first file in foo would be renamed to what the first file in bar is, the second file in foo to what the second in bar is etc.

So, just to be clear, following the renaming process "ls /path/to/foo" should yield the same output as "ls /path/to/bar". Although of course the actual content of all files in both foo and bar will not have changed.

(Note that all the files are of the same type, and some, but not all, contain spaces.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the dir trees.

Comment: What have you tried? We're not a code-writing service, we're here to help you fix problems in your code.

Comment: @kev It doesn't sound like he wants recursion, so I don't think the tree is relevant.

Comment: (a) Do any of the file names ever contain newlines? (b) Is using Perl or Python a reasonable option? (c) Is the ordering the sort order from `ls` (that is, the first file in `ls` order in `foo` needs to be renamed to the same name as the first file in `ls` order in `bar`)?  Alternative orderings include size, modification time etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `bash`, the secret lies in careful use of arrays (and double quotes):

```
x=( /path/to/foo/* )
y=( /path/to/bar/* )

i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#x[@]} ]
do
    base="${y[$i]##*/}"
    mv "${x[$i]}" /path/to/foo/"$base"
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly.